# golang yaml marshal url

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to work with configuration files which have url fields and I would like to marshal and unmarshal this type.
The documentation point that I can do a custom [marshal function](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3?utm_source=godoc#Marshaler).

In this golang playground you can see that the custom unmarshal function works fine but not the custom marshal function:

```golang
type YAMLURL struct {
    *url.URL
}

func (j *YAMLURL) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    fmt.Println("custom unmarshal function")
    var s string
    err := unmarshal(&s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    url, err := url.Parse(s)
    j.URL = url
    return err
}

func (j *YAMLURL) MarshalYAML() (interface{}, error) {
    fmt.Println("custome marshal")
    return j.String(), nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/24JbJEhi1Q8

I don't know why
Thanks

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/DPZaJGg5J7E (remove `*` from the MarshalYAML's receiver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote the `MarshalYAML` method for a pointer receiver, so you can call this method on a pointer type, meanwhile you defined the `URI` attribute of your `A` on `Configuration` struct, as a non pointer ( based on the playground link you pasted ).

So you have to either change the `URI` attribute type to `*YAMLURL` ( instead of `YAMLURL` ):

```
type A struct {
    URI *YAMLURL `yaml:"url"`
}
```

or define the `MarshalYAML` as a non-pointer receiver ( aka. Value receiver ), like this:

```
func (j YAMLURL) MarshalYAML() (interface{}, error) {
    fmt.Println("custome marshal")
    return j.String(), nil
}
```